# Create Table and assign a query as default value to a field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `williamhill` (
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `nick` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT (SELECT default_password FROM person p WHERE p.id = id),
    `Colonna 4` VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

How  can i do something like that in MYSQL? I'm trying to assign a default value from another table if no value has been specified during the creation of new row.

Is it possible like that or should i use a trigger/procedure?

Comment: Nope.  You can't do that.  You will have to use a trigger to set such a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is quite explicit that this cannot be done.  To begin with, the syntax for default is called default *value*.  A value is expected.

Here is how the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) describes this:

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. **With one exception, the default value
>   must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.**

(The one exception is `CURRENT_TIME` which most people probably don't even realize is a function.)

Many databases do allow function calls here.  None -- as far as I know -- allow query expressions.  However, that can often be emulated in a user-defined function.

The work-around is to use a trigger.  Looking up a value in another table is a fairly common use of triggers.